# Getting FATAL: No signature of method: hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.call() error

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am trying to execute below commands in Jenkins groovy script.

```
import hudson.model.*

def buildA = build("Master-Build")
println(buildA.getProject().getLastSuccessfulBuild())
```

and I am getting below errors

> 00:00:00.652 FATAL: No signature of method:
>   hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.call() is applicable for argument types:
>   (java.lang.String) values: [Master-Build] 00:00:00.652 Possible
>   solutions: wait(), save(), any(), wait(long),
>   each(groovy.lang.Closure), any(groovy.lang.Closure) 00:00:00.652
>   groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
>   hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.call() is applicable for argument types:
>   (java.lang.String) values: [Master-Build]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is this all code that you have in your script, or do you have anything before the `def buildA = ...`, especially something that assigns `build`, e.g.: `build = ...`?

Comment: Never mind, miss read, Where are you calling this from Build Flow Job definition or a build step of type `Execute groovy script`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the error it looks like you are calling `Execute system Groovy script` build step in a freestyle build. When you use groovy in that step, then the variable `build` is predefined to the current build and not a function for building other jobs (you might have confused it with the predefined functions/variables in Build Flow Job where the `build` variable is a function which starts a new build).

So in order to start a new build, you need to access the Jenkins instance directly and tell it to start a new job ([inspired by this script](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin#Groovyplugin-Retrievingparametersandtriggeringanotherbuild)):

```
// Import Jenkins
import jenkins.model.Jenkins;
// Get Jenkins instance
def j = Jenkins.getInstance();
// Get the job we wan't to trigger
def job = j.getItem("B");
// Finally we schedule a new build which starts directly (the zero in the argument)
job.scheduleBuild2(0)
```